# visual studio list workflow / move from test to live

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I created a sharepoint list workflow on my test environment.  On creation i had to select a list instance in the GUI.  Now my workflow is finished and i want to move it to my live environment.  The location of my list in the live is different from the location on the test server.  What do i have to change so that i can create a wsp file and deploy on the live?

Anyone a good article about this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to attach the workflow to your live list automatically when the solution deploys. To do this, select workflow, choose element property and set Target List.

[How do I associate a workflow to a custom list in Visual Studio 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22173/how-do-i-associate-a-workflow-to-a-custom-list-in-visual-studio-2010)

Or, to attach the workflow manually to your list (as long as there are no absolute references in your code, it should work as it does in dev), go to List Settings => Workflow settings (Make sure the feature is activated).

http://mscerts.programming4.us/sharepoint/sharepoint%202010%20%20%20associate%20a%20workflow%20with%20a%20list%20or%20library.aspx